# how to use other js plugin in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've encountered an issue recently where I want to use a 3rd party plugin in my nextjs practice project. Please note that I'm a React beginner, therefore, I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around the 'react way' of doing things.

My problem is that I do not know how to properly initialize/configure a plugin in a project.

For example, I want to use this [smoothscroll](https://previews.envatousercontent.com/files/225078175/index.html) js plugin. The regular static site approach is to add a script tag in the html files, and then initialize it by calling the plugin. eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new GambitSmoothScroll({
    amount: 150, // The scroll amount
    speed: 900 // The scroll speed
});
</script>
```

But in react, this approach does not work because of the virtual DOM. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing this in your `script` tag, in your app.js, where you main app is being initialized. In it's `componentDidMount` hook add this.

```
componentDidMount () {
  new GambitSmoothScroll({
    amount: 150, // The scroll amount
    speed: 900 // The scroll speed
  });
}
```

I am using here, that you include 'GambitSmoothScroll` at the top of your code. In order for this to use.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we use npm or yarn in React to manage package.I this particular 3rd party,I recommend you read this website [smoothscroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll)
you can run this in your terminal to add it.

```
npm install --save smoothscroll
```